# If $f$ is $\sigma(\mathcal C)=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable, does ther exists $f_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_n1_{C_n} \to f$ where $C_n \in \mathcal C$?

Tags: measure-theory

Given $f $, a real-valued, Borel-measurable function, may one claim that there exists sequences $f_n$ and $g_n$ of the *particular* forms 
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_n 1_{(a_n, b_n]}\right)_{n \ge 0}, \text{ and } \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_n 1_{[c_n, d_n)}\right)_{n \ge 0}
$$
converging to $f $? Here the emphasis is that sets of the form $(a_n, b_n]$ and of the form $[c_n,d_n)$ generates the Borel-sigma algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Or more generally, given any generator $\mathcal C$ of the Borel-sigma algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, does there exists a sequence of the form
$$
\left (\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_n 1_{C_n} \right )_{n \ge 0}, \qquad C_n \in \mathcal C
$$
converging to $f $?

Most grateful for any help provided!

Comment: this haves a positive answer when the generator is a semi-ring and the measure is $\sigma$-finite: this follows from theorem 1.65 in Achim Klenke's probability book. Im assuming here that you refer to convergence in $L^1$ (and this would imply the existence of a subsequence that converges in measure and pointwise a.e.)

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you! I wrote an answer myself. Did I get it as you intended?

Answer (score 1):

Following Masacroso's comment I wrote the following answer.

The solution is as follows. We utilize the following theorem.

> Theorem 1.65 in A. Klenke (2013)
>
> Given a semiring $\mathcal C \subset \sigma(C)$ and a measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(C)$ that is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal C$
>
> (ii) For any $A \in \sigma(C)$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ and mutually disjoint sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$ such that $\mu(A \Delta \cup_{i=1}^n A_i) < \epsilon $.

Thus given any simple function $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i1_{A_i}, \ A_i \in \sigma(C)$, for each $A_i$ we pick mutually disjoint $C_1^{(i)}, \dots, C_{n_i}^{(i)} \in \mathcal C$ such that $\mu(A_i \Delta \cup_{j=1}^{n_i} C_j ^{(i)})<\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha_i n}$. Then
$$
\left\|f_n - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\alpha_i1_{C_j^{(i)}} \right\| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \left \|1_{A_i} - \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}1_{C_j ^{(i)}} \right \| \le \epsilon
$$